# What's the best way to pass both a model and FormCollection data to my MVC 3 post controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Normally, when receiving form data in a controller, I'd use:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
```

I have a view which is bound to a model but also includes some items not attached to the model which I thought I'd be able to access via FormCollection as

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, MyModel objModel, FormCollection formValues)
```

I wondered if this is the best way to achieve this or if there's another to code this.

Comment: If you have same number of elements in HTML form and in Model then use MVC3 Model Binding. Have a look at this post. http://www.davidferguson.me.uk/Blogs/Post/introduction-mvc-3-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

If this is a post, you will need to tag the method with the `HttpPost` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formValues)
{
    var objModel = new MyModel();
    // updates model here
    TryUpdateModel(objModel);
}
```

In your view, you would have something like:

```
@model MyModel
... some html here
<fieldset>
   <legend>MyModel Information</legend>

   @Html.EditorForModel()
</fieldset>
```

So you can edit the model fields using the `EditorForModel` and retrieve those values using `TryUpdateModel`. Noting that you still have access to your `FormCollection` object.

Comment: Hi Seth - given it is an Edit, does he not need to grab the individual record from the db first with something like var objModel = db.Model .Where(i => i.ID == id) .Single() ?

Comment: That is what you would do in the GET method (e.g.`MyController\Edit\5`) to pass the model you want to edit to the view. Obviously you would need to update the db, which I haven't indicated after TryUpdateModel.

Comment: Agree with @Kevin's answer that `MyModel` should be a view model.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way to work. You shouldn't use your database model directly into your View.

You should pass a **ViewModel**. This way you can pass your model and extra properties.

```
public class MyViewModel
{

// All the properties for your model.

// All other properties needed and not attached to your model

}
```

In the Post action in your controller you can receive the **MyViewModel** and just make your model with the properties inside the ViewModel.

Check out this post for more information:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/01/26/view-models-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: I don't see a problem with using the model directly if it is a simple model and the mapping from the model to the view is one to one.....adding a ViewModel for the sake of it is just complexity for the sake of complexity

Comment: It's just much more cleaner for yourself and your colleagues. It also creates a consistency in your project if you use it everywhere. Plus in the future if more properties need to be added to the view this can easily be achieved without much code change and drama

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Unfortunately, I have a self-made check box list in this view which is not bound to anything in my ViewModel and I planned to parse through the FormCollection.  The following line is iterated for each checkbox I wish to add: @Html.CheckBox("product" + objRole.Role_ID, Model.UserRoles.Select(t => t.Role_ID).Contains(objRole.Role_ID));

Comment: The iteration shouldn't be a problem. Can you post your View into your original post as well?

Answer (score 0):

Before you get any further, read about difference between a domain model and a view model. Quite often, in a simple application you can get away with using a domain model. As the system grows, you are likely to encounter problems where simple features will be difficult to implement. Eventually you'll see a need to refactor code and this is when you are likely to see a need for a view model.

Your question is regarding parameters that are passed to controller actions. You have a controller to edit something.

There is an Edit GET where you do something like this:

1. Read data from database
2. Wrap it into the object
3. Pass this object to a view which will display the object

There is an Edit POST want to recieve data and write changes to the database. So what do you need to make that happen? You need id and a combination of fields that you wish to update. Passing FormCollection and something else means that you have to map values from FormCollection to your domain model. This is time consuming and a repetative task.

You don't want to do this, so you want submit back a single object, doesn't matter whether it's a view model or a domain model, but it should be an object that contains all the data that you need for an update.

Data binding feature of the MVC 3 framework will automatically map fields from the form to your model using clever reflection.

What you are doing is kind of works and it's a great way to learn. So don't give up. Refactor, see whether you can pass a single object and work with that.

Good luck